# Parse ClamAV scan file

Tags: anti-virus, clamav

I'm completely new to ClamAV
I am setting up ClamAV on one laptop located behind VLAN and I don't have the option to monitor result.
Still I need to know the result of the scan hence I decided to parse the log.
My question: what string should I expect if the scan revealed any suspicious activity ... like 'error' or 'fail' or 'infected' or etc.
Any suggestion what get into the log in case of infection?

Thanks

Comment: Use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file

Comment: Someone on ClamAV forum recommended me to check for word 'FOUND'. I did a test run and found a few instances of it e.g. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll: Win.Trojan.Pemalform-9786579-0 FOUND. Does it mean it could be an issue and it found something suspicious or I should search for something more reliable? P.S. Thanks for advice to try EICAR test file but I can't do it in my environment due to regulations. Thanks

Comment: Clam AV is notorious for its false positives, you may wanna check anything it found with (a) different scanner(s) I would recommend https://www.virustotal.com/